# How Can I go to preview page from Registration page and go back to the registration page from Preview page for modification

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

[image]

I want to register basic information in MySql database. But before registering the data, I want the user to preview the values, if he conforms the values he proceeds else he returns back and modifies his information. I want to do it using Ajax without a page reloading.

```
utils.js

    function createRequest() {
      try {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } catch (tryMS) {
        try {
          request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (otherMS) {
          try {
            request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          } catch (failed) {
            request = null;
          }
        }
      } 
      return request;
    }


    function getActivatedObject(e) {
      var obj;
      if (!e) {
        // early version of IE
        obj = window.event.srcElement;
      } else if (e.srcElement) {
        // IE 7 or later
        obj = e.srcElement;
      } else {
        // DOM Level 2 browser
        obj = e.target;
      }
      return obj;
    }

    function addEventHandler(obj, eventName, handler) {
      if (document.attachEvent) {
        obj.attachEvent("on" + eventName, handler);
      } else if (document.addEventListener) {
        obj.addEventListener(eventName, handler, false);
      }
    }

    Validation.js 

    window.onload = initPage;
    function initPage() {
      document.getElementById("register").onclick = registerUser;
    }

    function registerUser() {

      document.getElementById("register").value = "Processing...";
      registerRequest = createRequest();
      if (registerRequest == null) {
        alert("Unable to create request.");
      } else {
        var url = "register-feedback.php";
        var requestData = "username=" + 
          escape(document.getElementById("username").value) + "&firstname=" +
          escape(document.getElementById("firstname").value) + "&lastname=" +
          escape(document.getElementById("lastname").value) + "&email=" +
          escape(document.getElementById("email").value) + "&tastes=" +
          escape(document.getElementById("tastes").value);
        registerRequest.onreadystatechange = registrationProcessed;
        registerRequest.open("POST", url, true);
        registerRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",
          "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        registerRequest.send(requestData);
      }
    }

    function registrationProcessed() {
      if (registerRequest.readyState == 4) {
        if (registerRequest.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML =
            registerRequest.responseText;
        }
      }
    }

    registration.php

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
      <title>Mike's Movies</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/movies.css" />
      <script src="scripts/utils.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
      <script src="scripts/validation.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <h1>Please register to access reviews:</h1>
      <form action="register.php" method="POST">
        <ul>
          <li><label for="username">Username:</label><input id="username" type="text" name="username" /></li>

          <li><label for="firstname">First Name:</label><input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" /></li>
          <li><label for="lastname">Last Name:</label><input id="lastname" type="text" name="lastname" /></li>
          <li><label for="email">Email:</label><input id="email" type="text" name="email" /></li>


          <li><label for="tastes">Message:</label><textarea name="tastes" cols="60" rows="2" id="tastes"></textarea></li>
          <li><label for="register"></label><input id="register" type="button" value="Register" name="register" /></li>

        </ul>
      </form>

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>

 register-feedback.php

     <?php sleep(1); 

        echo "<h1>Welcome to Mike's!</h1>";
        echo "<p>Here's what you entered, " . $_REQUEST['firstname'] . ":</p>";
        echo "<p>Username: " . $_REQUEST['username'] . "</p>";
        echo "<p>Name: " . $_REQUEST['firstname'] . " " . $_REQUEST['lastname'] . "</p>";
        echo "<p>Email: " . $_REQUEST['email'] . "</p>";

        ?>

        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
                "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
          <title>Mike's Movies</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/movies.css" />
          <script src="scripts/utils.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

        </head>
        <body>

        <input id="cancelm" type="button" value="back" name="cancelm" onclic=cancelUser()/>
        <input id="sendm" type="button" value="send" name="sendm" />
        <div id="coverBar">

        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Could you post what you have tried so far ?

Comment: take a look at [jQuery Wizard](http://www.jquery-steps.com/), it may help you achieve what you need

Comment: Removed tag from title

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do that:

1) When user clicks on "Register" button first get all user details and don't submit, but instead open a modal and fill user details with data entered on form.

2) When user clicks on "Send" you pass data that are on that particular data and send with ajax.

I recommend to use JQuery instead

Answer (score 0):

Without any ajax and additional back-end.

Buttons should looks like:

```
<input type="submit" id="btn-submit" value="Register">
<input type="submit" id="btn-edit" value="Edit" style="display: none;">
<input type="submit" id="btn-preview" value="Preview">
```

And JS below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
        document.getElementById('btn-preview').addEventListener('click', showPreview);
        document.getElementById('btn-edit').addEventListener('click', cleanPreview);

        function cleanPreview() {
            // Show preview button
            document.getElementById('btn-preview').style.display = 'initial';
            // Hide edit button
            document.getElementById('btn-edit').style.display = 'none';

            var previews = document.querySelectorAll('span[id^="view"]');
            for ( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ) {
                var el = inputs[i];
                el.remove();
            }               
            var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="hidden"]');
            for ( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ) {
                var el = inputs[i];
                el.setAttribute('type', 'text');
            } 
        }

        function showPreview() {
            // Hide preview button
            document.getElementById('btn-preview').style.display = 'none';
            // Show edit button
            document.getElementById('btn-edit').style.display = 'initial';

            // Displaying inputs preview
            var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input:not([type="submit"])');
            for ( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ) {
                makePreview(inputs[i]);
            }
        }

        function makePreview(input) {
            // Hide input
            input.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
            // Get value and name
            var val = input.value;
            var key = input.getAttribute('name');

            // Make span
            var span = document.createElement('span');
            span.id = 'view-' + key;
            span.innerText = val;

            // Display preview
            input.insertBefore(span)
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I want to do it using Ajax and using two forms.